# nginx ssl_trusted_certificate directive not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-status

When I try to start the nginx server with this configuration I get an error

```
nginx: [emerg] no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify
```

My Configuration looks like

```
# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       4443;
    server_name  localhost;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/user/conf/ssl/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/user/conf/ssl/server.pem;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2;

    ssl_verify_client optional;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/ssl/certs/certificate_bundle.pem;

    include conf.d/api_proxy.conf;
}
```

As per the error, I should use `ssl_client_certificate` directive but as per the documentation if I don't want to send the list of certificates to clients I should  use `ssl_trusted_certificate`.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate

Can someone help me figure out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message itself:

```
nginx: [emerg] no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify
```

If you disable `ssl_client_verify` in your configuration, the error will disappear upon the next start of nginx. It appears that the semantics of `ssl_trusted_certificate` only pertain to its *exclusive* use and is subject to "logical override" when other configuration directives are in play.

I would *personally* prefer enabling `ssl_client_verify` to mean: "client certificates are verified if presented; clients are given no information regarding what client certificates or authorities are trusted by the web server". But, I can also see advantage in troubleshooting TLS handshakes when this information is available. From a security perspective, I only see *metadata* presented to the client via `openssl s_client`; there is no public key or other "signature-critical" information that a malicious client could use to, for example, attempt to clone/reconstruct the CA.

For example, running the following against a local instance of nginx with your configuration:

`openssl s_client -key client.key -cert client.crt -connect localhost:443`

... would show data similar in structure to the following in the response:

```
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/CN=user/OU=Clients/O=Company/C=Location
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
```

In my opinion, the value of the above is confined in value to troubleshooting.

Your DN structures are (ideally) not "security relevant" (especially if the context is an Internet-facing web service).

Comment: Nginx' documentation is misleading, OP's question is valid and this answer, to be honest, didn't clarify anything for me. So I don't want to provide metadata to the client, and there is directive for it. How to use it?

Comment: @EugZol It seems like the documentation is misleading and this is not possible. Have a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/938269/nginx-client-cert-verification-ssl-client-certificate-vs-ssl-trusted-certificat